# Why do I receive [object MovieClip] when tracing movieclips from an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

I want to put a set of onstage movieclip instances into an array, but I am getting object MovieClip instead of the instance name. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
var puz1_arr:Array = new Array (puz1.wMc, puz1.aMc);
trace(puz1_arr);
```

The trace gives me:
[object MovieClip],[object MovieClip]

instead of:
puz1.wMc,puz1.aMc

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the instance of a MovieClip, gives you the MovieClip as an object of type `MovieClip`.

If you want the name of the MovieClip object, simply use the `.name` property of the `MovieClip` Object.

Try this:

```
var puz1_arr:Array = new Array (puz1.wMc.name, puz1.aMc.name);
trace(puz1_arr);
```

This is assuming that `puz1.wMc` and `puz1.aMc` are `MovieClip` Objects.

Reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#propertySummary

Comment: Thanks! exactly the answer I needed.